# The solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}(y+a) =b$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

1-What is the solution of this differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot(a+y)=b $$

where 
$(a,b) \in \Bbb R$

2-What is the solution of this differential equation:

$$\frac{d²y}{dx²}\cdot(a+y)=b $$

where 
$(a,b) \in \Bbb R$

Comment: It looks to be separable, isn't it ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use the good ol' separation of variables:

$$\int(y+1)dy=\int kdx \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}y^2+y=kx+C$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$(y+a)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=b $$
$$(y+a)\ \mathrm dy=b\ \mathrm dx $$
$$\int y\ \mathrm dy+a\int\mathrm dy=b\int\mathrm dx$$
$$\frac12y^2+ay=bx+C$$
Now just solve for $y$. I'll leave the rest to you.